# In R, access indices stored in a list

Tags: r, dplyr, subset

I have a data frame df, and a list L of indices at which I should put 0 instead of the current values of df.

Example:

DF:

```
# A tibble: 11 x 3
      A     B     C
    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
    1724     4  2013
    1758     4  2013
    1612     3  2013
    1692     3  2013
    1260    33  2014
    1157    22  2014
    1359    63  2014
    1414    27  2014
    387     3  2016
    374     3  2016
```

L:

```
[[1]]
[1] 3 4

[[2]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

[[3]]
[1] 1
```

So in this example, I have to put zeros in rows 3, 4 of column A, in rows 1:5 in column B and row 1 in column C.

Is there a way to do it as a one-liner in R? A dplyr or R-base solution would be great! Also, I would like to avoid apply or loops since I have to do this very efficiently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop looks very fast to me. Haven't done the complexity comparison but if you have your replacement in list form and want to replace with 'val', just simply:

```
df
    a  b  c
1   1  1  1
2   2  2  2
3   3  3  3
4   4  4  4
5   5  5  5
6   6  6  6
7   7  7  7
8   8  8  8
9   9  9  9
10 10 10 10

val<-0
for(i in 1:length(L)){
  df[L[[i]],i]<-val
}

df
    a  b  c
1   1  0  0
2   2  0  2
3   0  0  3
4   0  0  4
5   5  0  5
6   6  6  6
7   7  7  7
8   8  8  8
9   9  9  9
10 10 10 10
```

I tested it on x, a 10,000 row and 10,0000 column df:

```
> b<-Sys.time()
> for(i in 1:length(L)){
+ x[L[[i]],i]<-0
+ }
> Sys.time()-b
Time difference of 0.490464 secs
```

Looks pretty quick :) I know it's obvious but hope it helps!

******** EDIT 1 ********

If we look at method by @mt1022 using unlist and cbind:

```
> b<-Sys.time()
> Lcol <- rep(seq_along(L), lengths(L))
> x[cbind(unlist(L), Lcol)] <- 0
> Sys.time()-b
Time difference of 7.467723 secs
```

Clearly much slower (because when we unlist, we essentailly loop through each and every element in L instead of each vector in L). ;)

Comment: Thanks for benchmarking my solution. It seems  "Matrix indexing (x[i] with a logical or a 2-column integer matrix i) using [ is not recommended" as described in the manual.

Comment: I should really read more manuals. Seems fair though, otherwise you would use the same memory unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1):

Another way using matrix of indices:

```
# DF <- read.table(textConnection('A     B  C
#     1724     4  2013
#     1758     4  2013
#     1612     3  2013
#     1692     3  2013
#     1260    33  2014
#     1157    22  2014
#     1359    63  2014
#     1414    27  2014
#     387     3  2016
#     374     3  2016'), header = T)
# 
# L <- list(c(3, 4), c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), c(1))


Lcol <- rep(seq_along(L), lengths(L))
DF[cbind(unlist(L), Lcol)] <- 0

# > DF
#       A  B    C
# 1  1724  0    0
# 2  1758  0 2013
# 3     0  0 2013
# 4     0  0 2013
# 5  1260  0 2014
# 6  1157 22 2014
# 7  1359 63 2014
# 8  1414 27 2014
# 9   387  3 2016
# 10  374  3 2016
```

Comment: Excellent answer. Perhaps you could have made it one-liner as `DF[cbind(unlist(mylist), rep(seq_along(L), lengths(L)))] <- 0`

Comment: @MKR Sure,  but one-liners compromise readability. Anyway, the major problem is that this method is too slow :(.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `mapply` in combination with `do.call`.

```
  do.call(cbind, mapply(function(x,y){
    df[x,y]<-0
    df[y]
  }, mylist, seq_along(mylist)))

  #         A  B    C
  # [1,] 1724  0    0
  # [2,] 1758  0 2013
  # [3,]    0  0 2013
  # [4,]    0  0 2013
  # [5,] 1260  0 2014
  # [6,] 1157 22 2014
  # [7,] 1359 63 2014
  # [8,] 1414 27 2014
  # [9,]  387  3 2016
  # [10,]  374  3 2016
```

**Data:**

```
  df <- read.table(text = 
      "A       B     C
      1724     4  2013
      1758     4  2013
      1612     3  2013
      1692     3  2013
      1260    33  2014
      1157    22  2014
      1359    63  2014
      1414    27  2014
      387     3  2016
      374     3  2016", header = TRUE)

  mylist <- list(c(3, 4), c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), c(1))
```